# VBA function returning recordset value from SQL Query

Tags: vba, ms-access, dao, recordset

I'm trying to return a currency value from a table, and I need to pass variables into a VBA defined function that contains a query in order to get the right one. I have the function used in a text box on a form, but it's returning:

```
#Name?
```

Any help is appreciated. Code below:

```
Option Compare Database

Public Function payrollVar(dateVar As Date, roleidVar As String, typeVar As String) As DAO.Recordset

Dim dbs As DAO.Database
Dim rsSQL As DAO.Recordset
Dim strSQL As String

Set dbs = CurrentDb

'typeVar must either be ODE, Actual, or Forecast

If typeVar = "Actual" Or "Forecast" Then
    strSQL = "SELECT [Master Data].[*Quantity]" & _
             "FROM [Master Data]" & _
             "WHERE ((([Master Data].[*Category])='Payroll') AND (([Master Data].[*Date])= " & dateVar & ") AND (([Master Data].[*Role ID])= '" & roleidVar & "' ) AND (([Master Data].[*Type])= '" & typeVar & "' ));"
ElseIf typeVar = "ODE" Then
    strSQL = "SELECT [Master Data].[*Quantity]" & _
             "FROM [Master Data]" & _
             "WHERE ((([Master Data].[*Data Version])='Resource_Detail_Cost_Increase_Projections_Table') AND (([Master Data].[*Category])='Payroll') AND (([Master Data].[*Date])= " & dateVar & ") AND (([Master Data].[*Role ID])= '" & roleidVar & "' ));"
End If

Set rsSQL = dbs.OpenRecordset(strSQL)

payrollVar = rsSQL.GetRows(0)

End Function
```

Comment: You don't have a default value for `Payroll` if there are no records.  Also, how are you accessing the values?  You are returning a recordset to a textbox as your comment on the line suggests.

Comment: You assign *strSQL* but never use it. Is the `OpenRecordSet` line missing? What is the end goal of function? And how is it called from textbox?

Comment: Sorry, yeah - it was edited too quickly before submission. I'm trying to get a single currency value returned from the query as a result of the overall function.

Comment: Where are you seeing `#Name?`?  I guess that you see the error value in a form field?  The function you shared returns a RecordSet object, so technically it will not return what you say it returns... it should either be a valid object or Nothing.  Anything else would result in an error, so what you are seeing is likely the result of Access automatically "handling" the error and displaying the error value back to you.

Comment: #Name? is the result of the textbox with this in the controlsource:
`=payrollVar(#7/1/2017#,"CE_013","ODE")`

Comment: There are a variety of problems with the code. 1) You cannot return an entire RecordSet object from a function and display it in a form control.  2)  The function says that it will return a RecordSet object, but the updated code is returning an array of values from the GetRows() function.  3) If you want a single value from the query, you need to get the value using other RecordSet methods like `rsSQL.Field(0)` or `rsSQL.Field("*Quantity")` or something.

Comment: Also, a hint for future use of StackOverflow.  In replying to a particular comment, using the '@' symbol followed by a user name.  Otherwise the user to which you reply will **not** get a notification and may never reply.  Click on the `help` link next to the Comment box for more information.

Comment: @CPerkins I changed the code to `rsSQL.Field("*Quantity")`, but same error. I'll keep hacking at it.

Comment: That's a step forward, but you need to address each and every issue that I mentioned.  What about the function return type?  It should be something like `As Currency`, not `As DAO.Recordset`.

Comment: I suggest [VBA Debugging](https://www.techonthenet.com/access/tutorials/vbadebug2010/debug01.php).  It is also useful to create a new module separate from a form and create stand-alone functions for testing code like this.  You can execute a public stand-alone function within the VBA Editor by either calling the test function from *Immediate Window* or pressing F5 while inside the function code.  If the function has parameters, you can create a separate test function which passes in dummy arguments.  Combine that technique with Debug.Print statements, breakpoints, etc.  Best of luck!

Answer (score 0):

Consider the [DLookUp](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/dlookup-function-8896cb03-e31f-45d1-86db-bed10dca5937) function instead of a DAO recordset retrieval which is not available directly to form controls like textboxes. Then, directly assign the value to your textbox in VBA and be sure to remove any `ControlSource` as textbox should be blank for VBA assignment.

Available in Access SQL and VBA, DLookUp's *criteria* argument can take any compliant SQL `WHERE` condition. Hence, you can reuse parts of your `SELECT` statement. Also, the function returns the first instance of a lookup if multiple values should return.

```
Public Function payrollVar(dateVar As Date, roleidVar As String, typeVar As String)
    Dim val As Variant

    If typeVar = "Actual" Or typeVar = "Forecast" Then

        val = DLookUp("[*Quantity]", "[Master Data]", _
                      "[*Category] = 'Payroll' AND " _
                       & "[*Date] = #" & dateVar & "#) AND " _
                       & "[*Role ID] = '" & roleidVar & "' AND " _
                       & "[*Type] = '" & typeVar & "'")

    ElseIf typeVar = "ODE" Then

        val = DLookUp("[*Quantity]", "[Master Data]", _
                      "[*Category] = 'Resource_Detail_Cost_Increase_Projections_Table' AND " _
                       & "[*Date] = #" & dateVar & "#) AND  " _
                       & "[*Role ID] = '" & roleidVar & "' AND " _
                       & "[*Type] = '" & typeVar & "'")

    End If

    ' ASSIGN TO UNBOUND TEXTBOX 
    Me.[myTextbox] = val

End Function
```

Then on the event trigger be it `OnClick`, `OnOpen`, `AfterUpdate`, etc. call the non-returned method:

```
Call payrollVar(param1, param2, param3)
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I too recommend using `DLookup` like Parfait suggests. I would go one step further and combine it with `IIF` so that a function is not even necessary, but that also depends on other factors. But if you do want to use recordset and assuming your SQL is correct this is what you are missing:

Instead of

```
payrollVar = rsSQL.GetRows(0)
```

you need:

```
rsSQL.MoveFirst
payrollVar=rsSQL![*Quantity]
rsSQL.Close
```

This generally is not enough! It is only good enough if you are assured that your query will return a value. If there is a chance it will find no record to return you need to enclose it in an if statement like this:

```
if rsSQL.EOF=False OR rsSQL.BOF=False Then
  rsSQL.MoveFirst
  payrollVar=rsSQL![*Quantity]
Else
  payrollVar=0 (or whatever value indicates no result found)
End If
rsSQL.Close
```

Finally, why on earth would you use `*` on a column name?? SQL is so much easier to work and read if you don't use spaces and symbols in names.